# How to deserialize Nested json of wcf service to object

Tags: json, wcf, deserialization

I've created a Web Service to receive data from Android json.

The json i receive is:

```
{
"assignmentId":"5476",
"newProductName":"ALGOBOX NET USB",
"Attributes": {
"Ammyy": "fvhbhgfc",
"Database": "h j j i i ",
"Plan": "555555555"
}
}
```

I want to deserialize the json and although i managed to deserialize the root elements, cannot deserialize the Nested:

```
"Attributes": {
"Ammyy": "fvhbhgfc",
"Database": "h j j i i ",
"Plan": "555555555"
}
```

The problem is that the attributes must be dynamic (Ammmy, Database, etc), so i cannot create a class with these strings. I want to deserialize the nested object to a Dictionary or KeyValuePair.

The classes that i've created are these:

```
public class RequestDataNewProduct
{
    public string assignmentId { get; set; }
    public string newProductName { get; set; }
    public List<Atts> Attributes { get; set; }
}


public class Atts
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

the C# typed equivalent for your json should look like -

```
public class Attributes
{
    public string Ammyy { get; set; }
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string Plan { get; set; }
}

public class RequestDataNewProduct
{
    public string assignmentId { get; set; }
    public string newProductName { get; set; }
    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

Then just deserialize it -

```
var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestDataNewProduct>(json); //success
Console.WriteLine(t.Attributes.Ammyy); //fvhbhgfc
```

Comment: The problem is that may the attributes be ammyy,database,plan at the moment but may change at any time. I want to make a dynamic class to read any string